# how to create dynamic ajax submission form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have 10 form in a page & there data is submitted through ajax, Now i don't want to create ajax script for each form. So here is what i tried

```
var form_id = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
      $(document).on("submit", "#"+form_id, function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
var postData = $("#"form_id).serialize()
var send = true;
var ptel = 1;

$("#"+form_id).find("input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === '') { send = false; ptel = 0; }
});
if(ptel == 0) { bootbox.alert('Please Fill All fields'); }
    if(send){
    $('form_id').trigger("reset");
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/X-Profile",
    data: postData,                    
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg)
 {

bootbox.alert('Your Profile has been updated.');
   }

});
}
return false;
});
```

var form_id results in undefined because when page loads no attribute was defined to it

Above codes are just to make you understand,
So my question is how can i make 10 forms submit through single ajax function

Comment: can't you do that on the button click of forms? Get the closest form id for that button and trigger an AJAX call

Comment: `$("#"form_id).serialize() `- missing a `+` - `$("#"+ form_id).serialize()`.  Also `$('form_id').trigger("reset");` - maybe wrong?

Comment: @Pete i have already told in the post that this code is just for reference it's just typing mistake in above code

Comment: @SagarSingh in future please take the time to type your code properly - if you can't be bothered to do that, why should we be bothered to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function such as SendForm() and attach it to the forms onsubmit attribute

```
<form id="yourid" onsubmit="SendForm(this);return false;">
```

inside the SendForm() function place your script

for instance:

```
function SendForm(form) {       
    var postData = form.serialize(); 
    // .......etc
}
```

To know which form was submitted in PHP, you can place a hidden input inside the form or have a second parameter on SendForm which gets sent through, such as SendForm(node,formtype)

if the form isn't submitting or page reloads, remove the onsubmit attribute and add this to your JS instead

```
$(document).on("submit","form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    SendForm($(this));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: could you please clarify what is node?

Comment: It's just the form your sending through to the function. I'll change the name to make it clear.

Comment: after submitting form it is refreshing the page

Comment: could be a number of things, but try the updated code

Answer (score 1):

Have javascript function like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function submitForm(formID) {
       data = $('#'+formID).serialize();
       //your ajax code
   }
</script>
```

Now use input button with onclick like below, and pass form Id as a parameter

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm({formID})">
```

This will work without refreshing the page. And on success you can trigger reset() function to form that particular form values.